# jQuery find pattern and get the element ID

Tags: jquery

I need to use the jQuery find built-in function and get the ID of the "found" form.

```
// workingForm is a valid obj and the jQuery selector is form[id$="frmAlert-"]
var workingForm = J('#tabs').find('form[id$="frmAlert-"]');

var idWorkingForm = J(workingForm).attr('id');
alert(idWorkingForm);
var idWorkingForm = workingForm.attr('id');
alert(idWorkingForm);
```

Why is the idWorkingForm always undefined?

Thanks!

Comment: It means the jQuery object was empty when you called `.attr` I.E. the selector used to create the jQuery object didn't match any elements.

Comment: I'll take a wild guess and say you should'nt be using the 'ends with' selector, but the 'starts with' selector = `J('#tabs').find('form[id^="frmAlert-"]');` ....

Comment: Also if you are not very sure where the string appears in the id, then you can use `J('#tabs').find('form[id~="frmAlert-"]');` else solution from @adeneo is perfect.

Comment: Thanks guys! You are fantastic! I continued to use an empty object in the script. (idWorkingForm had a length equal to 0). I had to use the wildcard ^.